# How should you reload a form and have it re-initialize?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

A older application loads some forms using implicit instances:

```
form2.showdialog()
```

Sometime between VS2008 32-bit and VS2013 64-bit, the forms stopped being initialized when they are reloaded. For example, if you load a form, close the form (using the Close method), and load the form again, the classes and controls (and, I assume, the form) are not initialized as new instances.

Re-initialization can be accomplished by putting `me.dispose()` in the FormClosed event, or by using an explicit instance of the form:

```
Using frm As New Form2
  frm.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

Is there a good reason to use one of these methods over the other, or is there another method that should be used to cause a form to be initialized when it is reloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Form object and its child controls are *not* automatically disposed when you display the form with ShowDialog().  That sounds pretty quirky but this was done for a *very* good reason.  After ShowDialog returns `DialogResult.OK`, you are normally going to obtain the dialog results.  What nobody likes is that failing because of a ObjectDisposedException.  Which would be likely to occur since the dialog results are often stored in controls.

You should always use the `Using` statement to ensure the form object and all of its controls are disposed.

A possible corner case is intentionally not disposing it because you like the redisplay the dialog with the original entered values.  Which is not completely wrong, it is however a *very* expensive way to preserve those values.  Those undisposed window objects cost an arm and a leg in system resources.

Answer (score 2):

Dispose will be called automatically if the form is shown using the Show method. If another method such as ShowDialog is used (your case it is), or the form is never shown at all, you must call Dispose yourself within your application. You can also handle the dispose by moving it from the designer file into the code file and handle things there as well.

On the other hand, `Using` statement  typically makes your application safer to maintain and less prone to deadlocks and other misbehavior related to the lifecycle of the resource. I would stick by using this approach.

Also you cant put `Me.Dispose` in the `Form Closed` event (possible issues). If your using `ShowDialog` it will fail as it will dispose your objects first, if you need them they are gone.

Here's more on dispose: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw58wzka(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Pretty clear explanation [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Unlike non-modal forms, the Close method is not called** by the .NET
>   Framework when the user clicks the close form button of a dialog box
>   or sets the value of the DialogResult property. Instead the form is
>   hidden and can be shown again without creating a new instance of the
>   dialog box. Because a form displayed as a dialog box is hidden instead
>   of closed, **you must call the Dispose method of the form when the form
>   is no longer needed by your application**.

When `ShowDialog()` called and closed, instance of the form will remain in the memory, and can be used again, for example get a result from some public property. 
If you not using anymore this form, you need to call `Dispose` method to dispose form and form's controls

```
Dim myform As New MyDialogForm()
myform.ShowDialog()
Dim result As Object = myForm.SelectedResult()
myform.Dispose() 'need to call manually, if instance not used anymore
```

When you use `Using` keyword then `Dispose` method will be executed automatically at the end of the `Using` block

```
Dim result As Object
Using myform As New MyDialogForm()
    myform.ShowDialog()
    result = myForm.SelectedResult()
End Using 'myform.Dispose will be called
```

Bottom line: Both methods doing a same things.
             But `Using` block will call `Dispose` method automatically

P.S. Putting `Me.Dispose` in the `FormClosed` eventhandler then
 - instance of the form will stay in the memory even form was closed
 - and will work only until you tried using disposed controls again. If you will try to show disposed object then `ObjectDisposedException` will be thrown.

If you not using form anymore then `Using` block will be best method

Comment: "If you will try to show disposed object then ObjectDisposedException will be thrown." I don't think this is correct. The disposed controls are re-initialized if the form is shown again, and no error occurs.

Comment: @xpda, cannot agree with you. This code: `Dim frm As new MyForm()` `frm.ShowDialog()`  `frm.Dispose()` `frm.ShowDialog()`  Last line will throw ObjectDisposedException with message _Cannot access a disposed object_

Comment: Interesting. If you put me.dispose in the MyForm's closed event, the error does not occur.

Comment: @xpda, exception will be thrown even you put `Me.Dispose()` in the `Form.Closed` event handler. Can you show your code which you using?

Comment: I added the code at the bottom of the question (temporarily). You can remove the closed event handler and form2 will not be reset on subsequent loads from form1. It runs both ways (VS2013).

Comment: @xpda, You using "VB.NET feature", where you are calling `ShowDialog()` method without writing code for creating a instance - `Form2.ShowDialog()`(Form2 is a type). This feature internally creating default **New** instance for you and calling `ShowDialog()` method with that instance. Your code are very expensive, because every time you press a button you create a new instance of the Form2. Notice that when dialog are closed instance not disposed and remain in the memory and keeps your expensive resources,